# Error in installing nachos 4.0 c++ version

Tags: nachos

1. I have been trying to install nachos 4.0 (c++ version), but on running the "make" command, I get the following error:

   gcc -E -I../userprog -I../threads start.cc > _/strt.s
   mips-xgcc/as -mips2 -o _/start.o */strt.s
   make[1]: execvp: mips-xgcc/as: Permission denied
   make[1]: *** [***/start.o] Error 127
   make: * [all] Error 2

I also tried giving all the permissions to the mentioned folder (mips-xgcc), but to no avail.

2. Also I had doubts regarding running user-processes. There is a sample code in the test folder, which performs matrix multiplication. To run this program one needs to convert the binary which is .coff format to .noff format (where .coff is the format of any a.out file in linux). My doubt is that since the example code contains statements which are peculiar to the MIPS architecture (e.g: Exit(C[Dim-1][Dim-1]) in "matmult.c"), how can we first compile the program as normal gcc and then use coff2noff to convert it into ".noff" format.

Is it possible that user-level process doesn't run because of the error mentioned in "1."

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You